# C IDE that lists the functions I've declared

Tags: c, function, ide, editor

Anyone know of a C IDE that lists the declared functions in the code on a sidebar?

- It would be nice to click to go directly to the function instead of scrolling a lot. The code I work with is unfortunately a bit monolithic.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Windows. Eclipse was perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, Eclipse is capable to show your code outline in the outline view.

See here: https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcoutline.htm